# 3D model breaks in nexus 4 with android 4.2.1

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality, jpct

I am trying to render a 3D model on marker in my AR app for android using JPCT-AE librtary.
I have tested it on nexus one and Samsung note 1, its working fine but same code and same 3d model not displaying properly in higher version phones like Nexus 4, sony xPeria z 6603 and Huawei android phone. 3D models breaks in to tiny pieces and hard to locate also. In my log it doesn't sow any error. 
So am not sure if it is problem of OS or hardware or program. any suggestion please?

Comment: Nexus 4, Android 2 ? Not sure what you mean ...

Comment: sorry my bad its version 4.2.1

Comment: If my memory serves, Galaxy Tab 2 latest OS version should be 4.1, and Nexus 4 should be on 4.3 or 4.4.

Comment: scratch that, I edited/ corrected it. my problem is if its because of android version I mean if texture supporting issue in new versions,  or 3D library that am using having some compatibility issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, It was fairly simple solution after all.
I forgot to clear the frame buffer every frame. Usually I should clear the frame buffer in ondrawframe() loop of jpct-ae, but it will clear the video background also, so we have to clear the framebuffer in Vuforia native code.
I still am not sure Why it was working in Note one though. I am glad its working in other phones as well now.